# Verify 2 Lists are equal based on element in parent class (in order too) in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

I have a class B which extends class A

```
abstract class A{
 Integer val;
}
class B extends A {...}
```

Now there is a list1 of class A objects, which I need to compare and check if they are equal in values and order as well, with another list2 I get after I apply a certain sort on the list1

```
B var1 = new B();
B.setVal(1);
B var2 = new B();
B.setVal(null);
B var3 = new B();
B.setVal(10);
B var4 = new B();
B.setVal(15);
List<B> list1 = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Now I have a sort method which gives list2

```
list2 = [null,1,5,10]
```

What method can I use to verify list1<>list2 ?

When I tried equals(), it is giving me list1 == list2

Comment: is `setVal` a `static` method or why are you calling it on the class and not the objects you create?

Comment: `List.equals` has the behaviour you're asking for. Please share a minimal reproducible example so we can understand exactly why you're not getting the expected behaviour.

Comment: Which `sort` method did you use and how you get `list2`?  For example, `Collections.sort` modifies the input list.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


abstract class A{
    Integer val;

    public void setVal(Integer val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public Integer getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
class B extends A {

}
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<B> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        B var1 = new B();
        var1.setVal(1);
        B var2 = new B();
        var2.setVal(null);
        B var3 = new B();
        var3.setVal(10);
        B var4 = new B();
        var4.setVal(5);
        list1.add(var1);
        list1.add(var2);
        list1.add(var3);
        list1.add(var4);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{null,1,5,10});
        List<Integer> list3 = list1.stream().map(B::getVal).collect(Collectors.toList());


        System.out.println("Both list are equal "+list3.containsAll(list2));
    }

}
```

Here I have converted bist of `B`'s object to list of `B.val` and then checked whether all the value in `list1` and `list2` are equal.

Comment: `List::containsAll` does not care for order of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare instance of `List<B>` to `List<Integer>` taking the order of the elements into account, first you need to check if both lists have the same size and then compare each element in both lists at appropriate position using [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) which may return `true` if both arguments are `null`:

```java
static boolean listsAreEqual(List<B> listB, List<Integer> listInts) {
    return listB.size() != listInts.size() ? false : 
        IntStream.range(0, listB.size())
                 .allMatch(i -> Objects.equals(listB.get(i).getVal(), listInts.get(i)));
}
```

Additionally, you may need to assume the lists equal when some instance of B is `null` (not just its `val` field) and appropriate `Integer` is `null`:

```java
static boolean listsAreEqualWithNulls(List<B> listB, List<Integer> listInts) {
    return listB.size() != listInts.size() ? false : 
        IntStream.range(0, listB.size())
                 .allMatch(i -> 
                     Objects.equals(
                         Optional.ofNullable(listB.get(i)).map(B::getVal).orElse(null),
                         listInts.get(i)
    ));
}
```